# How to add a language to JSPDF?

Tags: javascript, json, jspdf, non-ascii-characters

I'm using JsPDF and there's some problem with special characters. I'm creating a web-site pdf page where text is in Azerbaijani language (such letters as `Ə`,`Ş` are visualized). How can I fix this? Please help me

I've tried to use some custom fonts which must support those characters but the problems stays

```
doc.text(20, 40, "gəlirəm şabalıd");
```

output: `glirm abalıd`

Answer (score 1):

Try using a version of jsPDF >= 1.40 which supports UTF-8 characters. Which custom font are you using? I would suggest "Arial Unicode MS" or "Courier New", which can be found in system fonts.

As a final resort you could also try creating images with the problematic characters and replace the char with an image.

Comment: i tried Arial Unicode and that worked for me. Thank you very much!